# How can I get the RUN BUTTON in VISUAL STUDIO CODE to turn GREEN again?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, latex

I have been using Visual Studio Code for a couple months now and it has been fine. When I want to run some code, there is usually a little green triangle button in the top right corner that I can click on. Yesterday, that triangle turned white only for Python files (it is still green for Latex files) and when I click on it, most of the time nothing happens. When something does happen, it is often not right (I'm using Python to generate math worksheets in Latex. On the rare occasion that the run button responds to my click, the Latex worksheet is not generated correctly as it was before yesterday). Any ideas would be appreciated. I've already tried already restarting Visual Studio Code, restarting my computer, and uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio Code. Thank you!

Comment: I presume you've deleted your run configurations for python

Comment: If I did I don't know how. How can I check my run configurations? Is there a way to see if and when they were changed?